# How to do REST calls from Google Chrome

Tags: rest, google-chrome

Are there any plugins for Google Chrome to make REST calls?
Like the Poster plugin for firefox.

I have tried [chrome-poster](http://code.google.com/p/chrome-poster/), but it seems it still is on early development

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try this extension: [REST Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn)?

Answer (score 27):

You should also give a try to [Postman REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client-packa/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) (Packaged App), which is a fork from Simple REST Client. (There is also a [lite version](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) that runs in an ordinary Chrome tab and will suggest upgrading to the Packaged App version).

This extension is also open sourced on [github](https://github.com/a85/POSTMan-Chrome-Extension).

Here is a *short* of its features:

- Compact layout
- HTTP requests with file upload support
- Formatted API responses for JSON and XML
- HATEOS support
- Image previews
- Request history
- Basic Auth and OAuth 1.0 helpers
- Autocomplete for URL and header values
- Key/value editors for adding parameters or header values. Works for URL parameters too.
- Use environment variables to easily shift between settings. Great for testing production, staging or local setups.
- Keyboard shortcuts to maximize your productivity

Answer (score 2):

You should try: [cREST Client](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/baedhhmoaooldchehjhlpppaieoglhml).

Answer (score 2):

I would wholeheartedly recommend Advanced Rest Client:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

It was the only one that made POSTing form content really easy.

Answer (score 2):

And here is one more: [DHC by Restlet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dev-http-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm)

I tried a lot of them and this is the best one I've used so far.

Answer (score 2):

I used this [DHC by Restlet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-resthttp-api-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm?hl=en). We can pass the `session values as well as param` in very well manner.

Answer (score 1):

I this extension: [Simple REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fhjcajmcbmldlhcimfajhfbgofnpcjmb).